# Swift : addSubview before StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard

Im not new to swift but new to using storyboard, i typically do everything programmatically but decided to change it up a bit.

I have a storyboard with a bunch of UIButtons(numbers 0 - 9, similar to a calculator) and i would like to add a view on the lowest layer before all the buttons are added. So in terms of layers : UIView -> UIButtons

I thought simply adding the viewDidLoad() and putting the view first would work but it didn't:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    blurView = BlurViewEffect(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    self.view.addSubview(blurView)

    designButtons()   
}
```

Any idea how I can load the storyboard last?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but why not just `view.insertSubview(blurView, atIndex: 0)`?

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you! @Eendje

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to load the storyboard before the `viewDidLoad` method. Storyboards get serialized, so basically they're loaded with the `init:coder` method.

However, typical layouting tools should do the trick for your needs. Simply use `view.sendSubviewToBack(blurView)` to make sure your blurView is at the back of the view.